# Hadoop YARN concept

Tags: hadoop

I used to see Running Reduce Tasks and Reduce Task Capacity in JobTracker. In YARN ResourceManager, I do not see them any more.

Did we delete them? What is container and does it have to do something with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

YARN uses Node level Resource Managers (RM's) within which M/R tasks (including Reducers) may be allocated to run.  The Application Master tracks the progress of your M/R jobs and also has access to the containers supplied by the RM's to run the tasks.

Please look at the RM details to look further to track your applications (/jobs / map/reduce tasks)